# Fixed FLAT File to XML

Tags: xml, file, flat

Need some help on the XSLT 2.0.

Here is the request of a Fixed flat file that I get using unparsed text and a schema file having offset and length information using a document reference file. I am get all the details but when I start to do the grouping I am not able go further...Any help is greatly appreciated to move my stuck mind.

### Source Flat File

```
P01020 230039....
A30438 009090.....
A30439 009039.....
P02390 039438....
D03049 304830...
A30493 304030...
P30439 230300....
```

### Schema File:

```
    <Schema>
<Purchase recordIdentifer="P">
    <FIELD1 length="5" offset="1" type="xs:string"/>
    <FIELD2 length="6" offset="8" type="xs:string"/>
</Purchase>
<Account recordIdentifer="A">
    <FIELD1 length="5" offset="1" type="xs:string"/>
    <FIELD2 length="6" offset="8" type="xs:string"/>
</Account>
<Deposit recordIdentifer="D">
    <FIELD1 length="5" offset="1" type="xs:string"/>
    <FIELD2 length="6" offset="8" type="xs:string"/>
</Deposit>
```

### XSLT Code

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:param name="text-url" select="'test2014032901.txt'"/>
     <xsl:param name="file1" select="document('Schema.xml')"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:variable name="text" select="unparsed-text($text-url)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lines" as="element(line)*">
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($text,'\r?\n')[normalize-space()]">
                <line>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </line>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <Root>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$lines" group-starting-with="line[starts-with(., 'P')]">
            <Purchases>
                 <Purchase>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$file1/Schema/Purchase">
                            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                                <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($lines, ./@offset,./@length)"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
               </Purchase>
            </Purchases>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$lines" group-starting-with="line[starts-with(., 'A')]">
            <Accounts>
                 <Account>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$file1/Schema/Account">
                            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                                <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($lines, ./@offset,./@length)"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
               </Account>
            </Accounts>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$lines" group-starting-with="line[starts-with(., 'D')]">
            <Deposits>
                 <Deposit>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$file1/Schema/Deposit">
                            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                                <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($lines, ./@offset,./@length)"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
               </Deposit>
            </Deposits>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output XML is something as below

```
<Root>
    <Purchases>
        <Purchase>
            <Field1>01020</Field1>
            <Field2>230039</Field2>
        </Purchase>
        <Purchase>
            <Field1>02390</Field1>
            <Field2>039438</Field2>
        </Purchase>
        <Purchase>
            <Field1>30439</Field1>
            <Field2>230300</Field2>
        </Purchase>
    </Purchases>
    <Accounts>
        <Account>
            <Field1>30438</Field1>
            <Field2>009090</Field2>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <Field1>01020</Field1>
            <Field2>230039</Field2>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <Field1>01020</Field1>
            <Field2>230039</Field2>
        </Account>
    </Accounts>
    <Deposits>
        <Deposit>
            <Field1>03049</Field1>
            <Field2>304830</Field2>
        </Deposit>
    </Deposits>
</Root>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!.

Thanks

Comment: XSLT normally is used to transform ***from*** XML. With such a simple format I would use a programming language.

Comment: Thanks Joop, we cannot use any programming language with the tool we are using, just limited to XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the use of `for-each-group`, it seems, at least for the purchases, that

```
        <Purchases>
            <xsl:for-each select="$lines[starts-with(., 'P')]">
                <Purchase>
                    <xsl:variable name="line" select="."/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$file1/Schema/Purchase/*">
                        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring($line, @offset, @length)"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Purchase>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Purchases>
```

suffices to give

```
   <Purchases>
      <Purchase>
         <FIELD1>P0102</FIELD1>
         <FIELD2>230039</FIELD2>
      </Purchase>
      <Purchase>
         <FIELD1>P0239</FIELD1>
         <FIELD2>039438</FIELD2>
      </Purchase>
      <Purchase>
         <FIELD1>P3043</FIELD1>
         <FIELD2>230300</FIELD2>
      </Purchase>
   </Purchases>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, this is  extacly what I needed. thanks so much it worked